# Stochastic invariant subset

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let us consider a stochastic differential equation (SDE),

$$
dx_{t}=f\left(  x_{t}\right)  dt+\sigma\left(  x_{t}\right)  dW_{t}%
$$

and a compact set $C\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Given a stochastic Lyapunov function $\Phi\left(  x_{t}\right)  $ for this SDE
with respect to $C$, i.e.

(i) $\Phi$ is positive definite.

(ii) $L\Phi\left(  x\right)  $ is not necessary to be nonpositive in $C$ but
$L\Phi\left(  x\right)  <0$ for all $x\notin C$, where $L$ is the
infinitesimal generator of the SDE.

How can I prove that $C$ is an invariant set with respect to the solutions of
the SDE? In this I work with convergence in probability.

Answer (score 1):

This seems wrong to me. Consider $\sigma(x)=\sqrt{2}$ and $f(x)=-x$. Then $L=\triangle-x\cdot\nabla$. $\Phi(x)=|x|^2$ is a Lyapunov function with $C=\overline{B}_1(0)$. But $C$ is certainly not invariant.

Comment: Just after exiting the compact, is the probability of the state to return to C strictly lower than 1 or is always 1?

Comment: The probability of return is $1$.

Comment: How can I prove that?

Comment: This follows by Birkhoff‘s theorem.

Comment: I am not a specialist in this theorem, but it seems to mention Cosmology and Theory of relativity. How can it be applied to the stochastic problem that I pose?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory#Probabilistic_formulation:_Birkhoff%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem

Comment: @julian The return probability is $1$ in your example, but the assumptions of the OP don't even guarantee that, take BM in high enough dimension with $\Phi(x) = 1/|x|$ outside the unit ball. (Unless "positive definite" is meant to be "proper".)